# Escribir una función JS en un JsonGenerator

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, json

necesito generar una función dentro de un objeto json creandolo con JsonGenerator java
como la siguiente estructura

```
{
    "nombre": "bla bla",
    "edad": 20,
    "calcularAlgo": function(a,b){
         return a+b;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Y qué sucede? Añade más explicacion de que problemas/errores tienes. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) es un formato de texto para mandar información, no hay objetos JSON, sino objetos en Javascript de los que se puede generar un texto JSON. Y no se pueden meter funciones en un JSON a menos que pongas el código fuente como texto y luego la ejecutes con un `eval`